# retrieve value of one column from query asp.net

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I am writing project in ASP.
Data Access Layer returns all columns from database table.
I want to get value of on specific column and convert it to string.

For example I have

```
EmployeesTableAdapter eta;
```

and 
`eta.getData();` returns `"select *from Employees"` query.

How can I get the value of one speific column for example column FirstName?

Comment: are you looking to get the specific column for a specific individual or all data for that specific column?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string FirstName =  Convert.ToString(eta.getData().Rows.[0].["FirstName"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have to use a TableAdapter, use it to fill a DataTable

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
EmployeesTableAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
string FirstName = (string)EmployeesTableAdapter.Rows[0][0];
//Rows[0][0] Change appropriately
```